# Markerclusterer and infowindow v3 is not working properly

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, markerclusterer

I have used the sample code from google for markerclusterer. I added a code to display the coordinate of the marker in an infowindow for the markerclusterer v3 but the problem is it only loads the last marker latlang into the window: Can anyone help to resolve this issue.

```
  function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    });

    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
          dataPhoto.longitude);
      var info = dataPhoto.photo_id;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng


      });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    infowindow.setPosition(latLng);
    infowindow.setContent(latLng.toString()); 

    infowindow.open(map,marker);


    });
      markers.push(marker);

    }



    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
  }


  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  { 
  size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
  });

</script>`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I found the answer using the hint @geocodezip provided. The event addListener should be changed as follows:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(marker.position.toString());
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
```